# Boundedness for continuous Lipschitz gradient of multivariate functions?

Tags: derivatives, inequality, optimization, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous Lipschitz gradient, that is
$\|f'(x)-f'(y)\| \leq \lambda\|x-y\|$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is Euclidean norm and $x, y \in \mathbb{R^n}$.
If $x$ can be partitioned into $x=\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}$ where $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^p$, we have the following as continuous Lipschitz gradient statement
$$
\| f'(u,v)-f'(r,s) \| \leq \lambda \|\begin{bmatrix}u-r\\v-s\end{bmatrix}\|
$$
Can we put any assumption on the function or variables to get a bound based on the norms of $\|u-r\|$ and $\|v-s\|$?

I have tried by using $\|a-b\|^2 \leq 2\|a\|^2 +2\|b\|^2$
$$
\| f'(u,v)-f'(r,s) \|^2=\| f'(u,v)-f'(u,s)+f'(u,s)-f'(r,s) \|^2 \leq 2\| f'(u,v)-f'(u,s) \|^2 + 2\|f'(u,s)-f'(r,s) \|^2 \leq 2\lambda\|u-r\|^2+2\lambda\|v-s\|^2
$$
However, my last expression is in terms of square of the difference of the gradient and summation of expression of variables norms. Can I have a bound on the difference of the gradient based on the multiplication of $\|u-r\|$ and $\|v-s\|$ by assuming some new conditions on $f$? Something like 
$$
\| f'(u,v)-f'(r,s) \| \leq g(\|u-r\|\|v-s\|)
$$

Comment: You know that $\sqrt{a+b}\le\sqrt a + \sqrt b$ for $a,b\ge 0$? The product is not a good idea. What if one of the two factors is zero?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Could you explain?

Comment: No, I can't, sorry. It's trivial.